# Can't set KendoDropDownList window size

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to set the width of the drop-down window for a KendoDropDownList. using the following code:

```
<input id="dropdownlist" name="SelectedServiceLine"/>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var mdl = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ServiceLines));
        var ddl = $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: mdl,
            name: "SelectedServiceLine",
            dataTextField: "Description",
            dataValueField: "Description"
        });
        var dropdownlist = $("#dropdownlist");
        var kendoDDL = dropdownlist.data("kendoDropDownList");
        kendoDDL.list.width(400);
    });
</script>
```

the drop-down list shows and is a KendoDropDownList. So I know the call var ddl = $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList() is working. However, i get an exception when calling kendoDDL.list.width(400).

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'list' of undefined or null reference

the call var dropdownlist = $("#dropdownlist") returns an object. So the element "dropdownlist" does exist. But the call to dropdownlist.data("kendoDropDownList") is undefined. I'm not sure where to go from here to find the issue.  Obviously kendo is defined because the KendoDropDownList is getting rendered correctly. But for some reason I can't select the element and set the list's width property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, I was setting the "Name" property on the KendoDropDownList. However, "Name" is not a valid property. It should be this instead:

```
    var ddl = $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: mdl,            
        dataTextField: "Description",
        dataValueField: "Description"
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set the width like this.  It will automatically size the width to the largest item in the list.

```
$("#dropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList").list.width("auto");
```

**Update:**
You can also try this:

```
var ddl = $("#dropdownlist").css("width", "400px").kendoDropDownList({ ...
```

Comment: Good Idea and I will change it to auto. but the issue is when I call $("#dropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList").list, i get the error JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'list' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Looks like it should work.  Have you tried creating a jsFiddle to duplicate the issue?

Comment: Yes the drop-down list shows and is a KendoDropDownList. So I know the call var ddl = $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList() is working. It is styled like a KendoDropDownList and contains the correct values from the Model. So its something in the call to $("#dropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList"). For some reason that comes back undefined.

Comment: I can't recreate it in jsFiddle. It works just fine there. If var ddl = $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList() works, I don't see why $("#dropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList") doesn't.

Comment: Hey Rick that changes the width of the actual control not the drop-down window where all items are listed. It needs to be like this. http://jsfiddle.net/LSaZ7/1/